# Android calculator: Backspace button

Tags: android

I have recently designing for an android calculator, and the display is named fakedisplay.
i am now adding a backspace button for the calculator, and the code is as follows:

```
    backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 

            clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR; 
            String str=Fakedisplay.getText().toString();
            if (str.length() >=1 ) { 
                str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                Fakedisplay.setText(str);
                };
            if (str.length() <1 ) {
                Fakedisplay.setText("0");
            }
    });
```

My questions are that

1. I have tried the above and it works for inputs longer than 1 characters, eg 145 it will give out 14, when it is 14 it gives out 1, but when further pressed, the program will be forced-close. Why?
2. And how to consider for decimal input?

Would there be any better codes for this function?

Comment: haven't you heard of `else` clause for `if`? and for force close - check stacktrace in LogCat

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com, I'm not sure a simple if/else will work here because the first if _changes_ the length of string. The second if is _supposed_ to be a final catch, turning empty string into "0".

Comment: Show us more code! Your code above have no problem, maybe your calculator catch problem!

Comment: @Kingfisher the above code will never work check the condition

Comment: @droidhot: It worked for me! Inside the `if (str.length() >=1 )` will give an empty string! You could read more about string for java here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Comment: @pearmak: for decimal input, just add `android:inputType="number"` inside your `EditText`!

Comment: The code shown works fine, so the force-close must come from somewhere else. Have you checked LogCat?

Comment: Thanks for all your prompt replies! I have changed the coding to the answer below and it works! using the else if is the better way, because when the first if is met, it wont go to the second if. 

@Kingfisher: i have tired the answer below works well also for decimal point. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the code to

```
 backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        clearCalcDisplay = DONT_CLEAR; 
        String str=Fakedisplay.getText().toString();
        if (str.length() >1 ) { 
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            Fakedisplay.setText(str);
            }
       else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
            Fakedisplay.setText("0");
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain this isn't going to help at all. OP already ensures length is at least 1 so that you don't try to end up with a negative-size string. Your code disallows anything less than length 2 meaning that going from 14 to 1 will break. In other words, this seems to make it _worse._ By all means, let me know if my reasoning is incorrect. In any case, dumping code without an explanation is rarely helpful. You should expand it a bit.

Comment: @paxdiablo i hope if its set to <1 how will del the last number befr setting it to zero have you tried that try that and comment cause if the text is for eg 3 the length is 1 then you ll have to set it to zero

Comment: Lets say you start with "15" and press backspace. Length is 2 so it passes both original and your check, and the first `if` sets `str` to "1" with new length of 1. Your code then forces it to "0" prematurely (because your second if is wrong). And, even if it didn't, your code would then not allow another backspace to turn the "1" into a "", then "0" (because your second if is also wrong).

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the point. User can press backspace regardless of what's on the display. What I'm saying is the code as you currently have it will not correctly process backspace when the display is currently two digits in length - it will always set the display to "0". Follow the process in my second comment and it will hopefully be clear.

Comment: @paxdiablo i dont get that when length is 2 it will del 1 char and length is 1 char it wont enter the second if as there is an else over there and only if the btn is pressed again it will enter the second else dude

Comment: You added the else after my comments. Now I think it will work, but the `else if` is superfluous. Once the `else` kicks in, you _already_ know that the second `if` will be true since it's the exact opposite of the first `if`. I'd suggest cleaning that up.

Comment: @paxdiablo it was not created by me i copied it from the qtn and corrected the condition thats y i missed that else as normaly u wont check a condition thats opposite with another if and your comment was after my edit check the time dude

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16132/discussion-between-droidhot-and-paxdiablo)

Comment: My comments explaining why it was wrong are at 19 mins ago, 15 mins ago, and 10 mins ago. Your edit was 12 mins ago. So, while I hadn't noticed you'd fixed your answer for the last one, my first two were definitely correct. "Check the time, dude" sounds like an attempt at revisionism to me :-) In any case, I have no problems with your current answer since I think it will work, despite the unnecessary `else if`, so I'll say no more about it.

Comment: @paxdiablo no realy it was helpfull and i found my mistake what i said was about the last comment anyways its alr8 thanx for helping me find out my mistake i never meant (revisionism to me :-) ) anything like that i thought u were saying that it wouldnt wrk still after the correction thats why i said it only wrks when u press the btn

Comment: Thanks so much for both of you, really many thanks for the comments...paxdiablo's saying "for the second if the code then forces it to "0" prematurely" sparkles me, and hence i adopt the above answer suggested by droidhot and using else if, and it works nice, including the decimal place problem. 

However, while it works nice with the input, once i input 145 then press any manipulation (+ - * / or other functions) and then press backspace, it will force close too. This is another problem arised though, and I am figuring it out how to solve. Really thanks for all your comments!!

Answer (score 0):

I combined both codes and got the perfect code

```
backspace.setOnClickListener(new             View.OnClickListener() {        
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 


        String str=Fakedisplay.getText().toString();
        if (str.length() >=1 ) { 
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
            Fakedisplay.setText(str);
            } else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
        Fakedisplay.setText("0");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

//Needed an extra closing bracket. If you don't include the 0 and just leave //"" instead you will have a blank space instead of a zero.

```
backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String str = Fakedisplay.getText().toString();
                if (str.length() > 1) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
                    Fakedisplay.setText(str);
                } else if (str.length() <= 1) {
                    Fakedisplay.setText("0");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply did this:

```
void delete(EditText expr) {
        String str = expr.getText().toString();
        if(str.length() == 0)
            return;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        expr.setText(str);
}
```

And I used the xml onclick element.
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str=Fakedisplay.getText().toString();
    if (str.length() >1 ) { 
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        Fakedisplay.setText(str);
        }
   else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
        Fakedisplay.setText("0");
    }
```

**I used this code in the buttonBackspace public void section **